# Error in plotting a polar plot using scilab

Tags: plot, scilab

at line     5 of executed file C:\Users\LAPTOP\8a.sce

Inconsistent row/column dimensions.

```
clc
close
clf
s=0:.1:2*%pi;
h=10/(1+5*s);
polarplot(s,h);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the elementwise division (`./`) to generate `h`. Try changing line 5 to

```
h=10./(1+5*s)
```

and rerun.